# android filter custom array adapter and bring back old items again

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter

I am actually trying to filter my ListView with a text.

If I type something, the results getting filtered, but if I delete my typed text again, the list is empty. :(

Do you know how I could fix that?

Here's the code so far:

```
public class ResultsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SuchErgebnis> {

    Context myContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ergebnisListeOriginal = null;
    ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ergebnisListeGefiltert = null;
    private Filter filter;

    public ResultsArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.myContext = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.ergebnisListeOriginal = objects;
        this.ergebnisListeGefiltert = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ErgebnisHolder eHolder = null;
        SuchErgebnis ergebnis = ergebnisListeGefiltert.get(position);

        if (row == null) // Wird zum ersten Mal gelanden...
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ergebnis_list_item, parent, false);

            eHolder = new ErgebnisHolder();
            eHolder.eTitel = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_titel);
            eHolder.eInfo = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_info);
            eHolder.eTreffer = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_treffer);

            row.setTag(eHolder);
        } else { // Wurde schoneinmal geladen, Views sind noch gespeichert...
            eHolder = (ErgebnisHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        eHolder.eTitel.setText(ergebnis.titel);
        eHolder.eInfo.setText(ergebnis.info != null ? ergebnis.info : "");
        eHolder.eTreffer.setText(ergebnis.treffer != null ? ergebnis.treffer
                : "");
        row.setPadding(
                ergebnis.isChild ? Main.mFHelper
                        .getPixels(10 * ergebnis.childNumber) : 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ResultFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    static class ErgebnisHolder {
        TextView eTitel;
        TextView eInfo;
        TextView eTreffer;
    }

    private class ResultFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            String filterText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (filterText == null || filterText.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    results.values = ergebnisListeOriginal;
                    results.count = ergebnisListeOriginal.size();
                }
            } else {
                ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> gefilterteListe = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>();
                ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ungefilterteListe = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>();
                synchronized (this) {
                    ungefilterteListe.addAll(ergebnisListeOriginal);
                }
                for (int i = 0, l = ungefilterteListe.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    SuchErgebnis m = ungefilterteListe.get(i);
                    if (m.titel.toLowerCase().contains(filterText)) {
                        gefilterteListe.add(m);
                    }
                }
                results.values = gefilterteListe;
                results.count = gefilterteListe.size();

            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            ergebnisListeGefiltert = (ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>) results.values;
//          notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = ergebnisListeGefiltert.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(ergebnisListeGefiltert.get(i));
//          notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }

    }

}
```

Edit://

The filter is called by a simple Textwatcher

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};
```

Which i add to the EditText via

```
etFilter.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed whether `performFiltering()` is called when the text in your search box is empty?

Comment: Add code where do you performFiltering?

Comment: The performFiltering() is called when the text is empty. But even if its not empty but smaller than the previously text, the old items wont show up (They getting somewhere deleted from ergebnisListeOriginal...

Comment: Its working now :) Edited first post.

Comment: Don't edit the question, instead provide an answer with the solution and mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's my first post :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution:

```
 public class ResultsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SuchErgebnis> {

    Context myContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ergebnisListeOriginal = null;
    ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ergebnisListeGefiltert = null;
    private Filter filter;

    public ResultsArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.myContext = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;

        this.ergebnisListeOriginal = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>(objects);
        this.ergebnisListeGefiltert = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>(objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ErgebnisHolder eHolder = null;
        SuchErgebnis ergebnis = ergebnisListeGefiltert.get(position);

        if (row == null) // Wird zum ersten Mal gelanden...
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ergebnis_list_item, parent, false);

            eHolder = new ErgebnisHolder();
            eHolder.eTitel = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_titel);
            eHolder.eInfo = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_info);
            eHolder.eTreffer = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.ergebnis_list_item_textview_treffer);

            row.setTag(eHolder);
        } else { // Wurde schoneinmal geladen, Views sind noch gespeichert...
            eHolder = (ErgebnisHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        eHolder.eTitel.setText(ergebnis.titel);
        eHolder.eInfo.setText(ergebnis.info != null ? ergebnis.info : "");
        eHolder.eTreffer.setText(ergebnis.treffer != null ? ergebnis.treffer
                : "");
        row.setPadding(
                ergebnis.isChild ? Main.mFHelper
                        .getPixels(10 * ergebnis.childNumber) : 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ResultFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    static class ErgebnisHolder {
        TextView eTitel;
        TextView eInfo;
        TextView eTreffer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ergebnisListeGefiltert.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SuchErgebnis getItem(int position) {
        return ergebnisListeGefiltert.get(position);
    }

    private class ResultFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            String filterText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (filterText == null || filterText.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    results.values = ergebnisListeOriginal;
                    results.count = ergebnisListeOriginal.size();
                }
            } else {
                ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> gefilterteListe = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>();
                ArrayList<SuchErgebnis> ungefilterteListe = new ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>();
                synchronized (this) {
                    ungefilterteListe.addAll(ergebnisListeOriginal);
                }
                for (int i = 0, l = ungefilterteListe.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    SuchErgebnis m = ungefilterteListe.get(i);
                    if (m.titel.toLowerCase().contains(filterText)) {
                        gefilterteListe.add(m);
                    }
                }
                results.values = gefilterteListe;
                results.count = gefilterteListe.size();

            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            ergebnisListeGefiltert = (ArrayList<SuchErgebnis>) results.values;
            if(results.count > 0)
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }


        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The only example I found that makes sense (apart from the auto-translations for `ergebnisListeGefiltert`, `ergebnisListeOriginal` etc for which I thank Google. ;)

Comment: Although I need in `publishResults` to drop `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` and leave only `notifyDataSetChanged()` for all `result.count` values. Otherwise an empty constraint won't reset the list to the original "unfiltered" values [I think this is worth another S.O. question].

Comment: I think I tried to follow the method but I am still having some issues. Please take a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function